# How to fix the error 'TypeError: can't pickle time objects'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opc

I am using the OpenOPC library to read data from an OPC Server, I am using 'Matrikon OPC Simulation Server', when I try to read the data it sends me the following error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle time objects
```

The code I use is the following, I run it from the python console.

**CODE:**

```
import OpenOPC
opc = OpenOPC.client()
opc.connect('Matrikon.OPC.Simulation')
opc.read('Random.Int4')
```

When I run the line opc.read ('Random.Int4'), that's when the error appears.

This is how the variable appears in my MatrikonOPC Explorer:
[image]

This is the complete error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 264, in _feed
    send(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle time objects
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\OPC2\venv\lib\site-packages\OpenOPC.py", line 625, in read
    return list(results)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\OPC2\venv\lib\site-packages\OpenOPC.py", line 543, in iread
    raise TimeoutError('Callback: Timeout waiting for data')
TimeoutError: Callback: Timeout waiting for data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding `sync=True` when calling `opc.read()`

**CODE:**

```
import OpenOPC
opc = OpenOPC.client()
opc.connect('Matrikon.OPC.Simulation')
opc.read('Random.Int4', sync=True)
```

- Reference: [mkwiatkowski/openopc](https://github.com/mkwiatkowski/openopc/pull/4/commits/80099d318e59e7ec848e743e4c10a27968380eac)